# Correct usage of Python threading.RLock

Tags: python, multithreading

I haven't used the `threading` library much in Python, so my confidence is a little shaky compared to concurrency in other languages... is this a correct way to use a [`threading.RLock()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#using-locks-conditions-and-semaphores-in-the-with-statement) object as a mutex?

```
class MyObj(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.mutex = threading.RLock()

    ...

    def setStatistics(self, statistics):
        with self.mutex:
            self._statistics = statistics
    def getStatistics(self):
        with self.mutex:
            return self._statistics.copy()
```

In particular I want to make sure that the `self._statistics.copy()` step happens while the mutex is still acquired.

Is there any other gotcha I need to be aware of? The `self._statistics` object is a large numpy array and I need to make sure it is transferred properly and in a consistent state between threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, that's the right way to use it. When you use this statement:

```
with self.mutex:
    return self._statistics.copy()
```

The lock won't be released until *after* the `self._statistics.copy()` operation completes, so its safe. Here's a demo:

```
import threading

class MyLock(threading._RLock):
    def release(self):
        print("releasing")
        super(MyLock, self).release()

class Obj():
    def test(self):
        print "in test"

l = MyLock()
obj = Obj()

def f():
    with l:
        return obj.test()

f()
```

Output:

```
in test
releasing
```

Comment: I wouldn't call it "proof" (concurrency proofs are very difficult), but it's a good demonstration.

Comment: @JasonS Yes, "proof" wasn't a great word choice there. I'll edit it.